# Can't connect to SQL Server using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, netbeans

I'm having issues connecting to a Database server with the JDBC driver in Netbeans. I've tried everything, enabling TCP/IP, opening the ports, I've followed tutorials online. It just won't work.

This is the error message I get in the console:

`Information: Error: The TCP / IP connection could not be made to the MANUEL-PC host, port 1433. Error: "Connection refused: connect Verify the connection properties, check that there is an instance of SQL Server running on the host and accepting TCP / IP connections on the port and verify that there is no firewall blocking TCP connections on the port. "`

Start of the class we're using...

```
 public class DBPosteo
{
    private final String URL ="jdbc:sqlserver://MANUEL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=DLC_MotorDeBusqueda;integratedSecurity=true"; 


    private Connection con;
    String query = "";
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    public void init()
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    }
```

[DB Server name in SQL Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HFTh.png)

Thanks in advance for the help... I've never struggled so much with Databases in my life :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remove the port number**.

Only specify either instance name (`SQLEXPRESS`) *or* port number (`1433`), never both.

Since port `1433` is reserved for the unnamed instance, the `SQLEXPRESS` named instance would be on a different port, and unless you specifically configured it (unlikely), that port is dynamic and can change on reboots, so you need the named lookup.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much... I've spent the past 2 hours doing a lot of configuration settings and the answer was so simple! I won't hesitate again in asking here in the future...